# Even Factorial Method in Java. I have tried everything and can't figure it out

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, factorial

Ok in this method I am supposed to compute the factorial using only the evens. So for example if I inputed 7 for n I would expect 6*4*2 = 48. I am supposed to fix the code so it will work. I have tried for like an hour now and don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
int p07EvenFactorial(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 1) {
        n--;
    }
    int fact = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        fact = fact + 2 * i;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

Comment: If you only want to use the even numbers, wouldn't it then make sense to reduce `i` by two, instead of one and use `fact *= i;`?

Comment: How would you write this if it wasn't code? Think of the problem in English first, find the pattern (the loop), and THEN convert it to code.

Comment: By the way, Wikipedia says it is called [even double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
int p07EvenFactorial(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 1) {
        n--;
    }
    int fact = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i = i + 2) {
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
public int fact(int n) {
        if(n % 2 ==1){
            n = n -1;
        }
        if(n == 0){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return n*fact(n-2);
        }
}
```